Getting Error Failed to construct kafka consumer
caused by: org.apache.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap url given in bootstrap.server
While I am adding this in the configuration:
@Configuration
class TopicConfiguration {

private ConsumarFactory<String, String> creteConsumer(String id) {
Map<String, String> config = new hashMap<>();
config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVER_CONFIG, configProperties.getBootstrapServers);

When I am adding it like
config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVER_CONFIG, "localhost://8080"));

it is working but I have to get the bootstrap servers from properties file

Yes you have to provide details of kafka to consumer,so that it will connect to kafka.

There is kafkaConfig class that you can use.
I used a custom object named KafkaTransferDto

public class KafkaTransferDto {

    private Object object;

    private String topic;


    public Object getObject() {
        return object;
    }

    public void setObject(Object object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    public String getTopic() {
        return topic;
    }

    public void setTopic(String topic) {
        this.topic = topic;
    }

  
}

import com.pns.dto.KafkaTransferDto;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.*;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Value(value = "${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;
    private final String groupId = "PNS";


    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, KafkaTransferDto> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, KafkaTransferDto> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }


    public ConsumerFactory<String, KafkaTransferDto> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        JsonDeserializer<KafkaTransferDto> deserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>(KafkaTransferDto.class, false);
        deserializer.addTrustedPackages("*");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), deserializer);
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, KafkaTransferDto> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, KafkaTransferDto> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
}


And this is my application.yml

spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:mydb
    username: sa
    password: password
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092

server:
  port: 8051

